# What is Sirius Black's boggart?

Tags: harry-potter, sirius-black

I can't find any canonical reference on this site.

**Do we know what Sirius Black's boggart form is?**

Comment: Angry fans on twitter.

Comment: an 8th story that reads like bad fan fiction

Comment: It's his mother.

Comment: @ThruGog - He hates her, he doesn't *fear* her

Comment: May I know why this question was heavily downvoted? I just want to know the reason.

Answer (score 6):

### Canon

**We don't know Sirius' Boggart form.** It's not explicitly stated in any of the novels, nor has it been revealed in any of JKRs [posted interviews](http://www.accio-quote.org/), nor via her [twit feed](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor), nor on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/boggart).

### Guesswork time

There's always the possibility that it's a Dementor or Azkaban Prison itself, but given the extreme risks Sirius Black takes to see his godson at the train station and to watch him playing Quidditch, I think we can be reasonably sure that his boggart would have been **Harry's dead body**. In earlier years, it was probably James Potter's dead body.

> *Harry turned his back on Dumbledore and stared determinedly out of the
> window. He could see the Quidditch stadium in the distance. Sirius had
> appeared there once, disguised as the shaggy black dog, so he could
> watch Harry play … he had probably come to see whether Harry was as
> good as James had been … Harry had never asked him …*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</sup></sub>